# Eevee - Light inside a bulb lamp not passing through glass

Tags: eevee-render-engine, lighting, glass

Using Eevee, I'm trying to simulate a light bulb.
I have a sphere with glass material and inside it, I have a Point light.
But the light is not passing through the glass:

[image]

However, if I disable the sphere object, the light is working:

[image]
[image]

How to make the light inside a bulb lamp pass through glass (using Eevee)?

Here my test project:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing shadow mode from opaque to None will allow your light to pass through. And changing blend mode from alpha clip to alpha hashed will give you a more realistic looking glass. Enable screen space reflection too in render tab

Also, change your shader material to this:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but you see that the sphere is being rendered with flat faces, even with Shade Smooth activated for it. How to solve this?

Comment: @RogérioDec it doesn't for me try adding a subdivision modifier

Comment: Tks, but if you look into your own image you'll see that the sphere is being rendered in a not smooth shading, you clearly can see the faces and edges... the sphere should be smooth...

Comment: @RogérioDec that's because I didn't give shade smooth